# Why does React's usePrevious function work in this MDN focus management example?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm working through this tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Client-side_JavaScript_frameworks/React_accessibility

I understand that useEffect() runs after the initial render, but why is it that usePrevious() retrieves the previous value? I would assume it retrieves the current value because it runs after every render and saves the current value of `editing`.

```
    const [editing, setEditing] = useState(false);
    const wasEditing = usePrevious(editing);


    useEffect(() => {

    if(!wasEditing && editing){
        editFieldRef.current.focus();
    }
    if(wasEditing && !editing){
        editButtonRef.current.focus();
    }

    }, [wasEditing,editing])

    function usePrevious(value){
      const ref = useRef();
      useEffect(() => {
          ref.current = value;
      })
      return ref.current;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following happens:

1. Synchronous execution during render:

   1. `usePrevious` gets called
   2. `useEffect` schedules an effect
   3. With `return ref.current` the current value gets returned and stored into `wasEditing`
2. The effects run:

   1. The effect in `usePrevious` runs and sets `ref.current`
   2. The effect in the component runs and accesses `wasEditing` (not `ref.current`!)

Thus when `ref.current` is read in the synchronous part of the render, it will always copy the value of the previous render into the local variable.