# Why does React's usePrevious function work in this MDN focus management example? Clarification needed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state, react-ref

There was a question already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68785988/why-does-reacts-useprevious-function-work-in-this-mdn-focus-management-example) but I needed some clarification.

```
const [editing, setEditing] = useState(false);
const wasEditing = usePrevious(editing);

useEffect(() => {
  if(!wasEditing && editing){
    editFieldRef.current.focus();
  }
  if(wasEditing && !editing){
    editButtonRef.current.focus();
  }
}, [wasEditing,editing])
```

```
function usePrevious(value){
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
      ref.current = value;
  })
  return ref.current;   // <=== THIS LINE HERE
}
```

According to what I understood, because the previous answer missed a few steps. The priority of running goes like this:

1. The useEffect() functions run
2. The rest of the code runs (the line I have added a comment into)

When and why does the usePrevious function run again?

Comment: I've updated [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68786040/1048572), does it make more sense now?

Comment: you have it backwards, the `useEffect` runs *after* the rest of the code, so the `ref.current` that's returned is indeed the "previous" value - ie the value the `ref` had before it became `value`.

Comment: 1. usePrevious runs returns undefined
2. usePrevious runs sets ref.current = false // This has already been returned though?
3. I click edit, editing turns to true
What follows?

Comment: @Dimitrios initially it returns `undefined`. You can play with it here: [https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-thunder-tw3fmv?file=/src/App.js](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-thunder-tw3fmv?file=/src/App.js)